# Could not locate device support files. iPhone 7 running iOS 11.1 (15B93)

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using XCode Version 9.0 (9A235) which doesnt support iOS 11.1 (15B93).And i can not update to XCode 9.1 due to some reason.
So , could someone please share the required support files? or do we have any other option?

[image: Error from XCode]

Comment: If you want to down vote , please mention why you do it.....

Comment: check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129893/does-anyone-has-ios-11-1-15b93-develop-disk-image

Comment: @Rajat those are different support files(15B5078b), i need 15B93.

Comment: @Rajat Thanks, i used these files https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxsJTxRlRZWmRHpNSDQ3QWg1VTQ/view  , renamed them as 15B93 and it works.

Comment: @Ragav Thank you so much! it works like charm!

Comment: where can I get for iOS 11.2.2?
this is my error.
This iPhone 6 Plus is running iOS 11.2.2 (15C202), which may not be supported by this version of Xcode.

Comment: Hi @hkg328 , Try this support file by renaming them to 15C202 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AYfp4KT4G2_avwch0gsU_AT7GVnEDFLP/view?usp=sharing